# textfields collapsed after sencha cmd build

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

I am using the lastest sencha cmd for the build with ext-5.0.1.
Everythings look good during the development status (http://www.imageupload.co.uk/5Med) but after the build.
All the textfields collapsed like shown (http://www.imageupload.co.uk/5MeQ), and have no response to the changes in width, minWidth, flex... etc.
And also the properties y and x are not functioning.

If someone had had similar situation before, please help, thx

My cmd is v5.0.3.324

Here are part of my code:

In my Main.js:

```
Ext.define('ExtTest2.view.main.Main', {
    extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
    requires: [
        'ExtTest2.view.main.MainController',
        'ExtTest2.view.main.MainModel'
    ],

    xtype: 'app-main',

    controller: 'main',
    viewModel: {
        type: 'main'
    },

    layout: {
        type: 'fit'
    },

    itemId:'Stage'
});
```

MainController.js:

```
Ext.define('ExtTest2.view.main.MainController', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.ViewController',

    requires: [
    ],

    alias: 'controller.main',

    init: function(){
        this.Start();
    },

    Start: function(){
        var data = {
          itemId: "Page_Login",
          xtype: "panel",
          items: [
            {
               padding: 30,
               layout:{
                 type: 'vbox',
                 align: 'center'
               },
               xtype: "fieldset",
               y: "30%",
               height: 150,
               items: [
                 {
                    xtype: "textfield",
                    itemId: "Textfield_Username",
                    fieldLabel: "用戶名稱",
                    labelStyle: "color:#FFFFFF"
                 },
                 {
                    fieldLabel: "密碼",
                    itemId: "Textfield_Password",
                    labelStyle: "color:#FFFFFF",
                    xtype: "textfield"
                 },
                 {
                    itemId: "Button_Login",
                    text: "登入",
                    width: 100,
                    xtype: "button"
                 }
               ]
            }
          ] 
        };
        var container = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#Stage')[0];
        container.removeAll();
        container.add(data);
        container.updateLayout();
    }
});
```

Comment: What is the exact version of Cmd? Also, provide please some code so that somebody can reproduce your issue.

Comment: OK, I 've included the detail you may need

Answer (score 1):

1. It is overnested because you add unnecessary container to `app-main` containing the fields.
2. It is very unusual to manipulate views from view controller like that - create a class for the fieldset, give it an alias (xtype) and simply instantiate that. Cramming controller handlers together with view definitions shall inevitably lead to [Spaghetti Code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code).
3. You use vbox layout, without any flex or height to hold form fields. Form fields behave best in anchor layout that is the default for Ext.form.Panel.